# rails controller not accepting params from rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm trying to create a new controller, i'm following the getting started tutorial. I've renamed articles to investments for something different. I keep getting the following error relating to my controller

```
myapp/app/controllers/investments_controller.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
```

The controller looks like this:

```
class InvestmentsController < ApplicationController

def show
@investment = Investment.new(params.require(:investment).permit(:title, :text))
end

def new
end

def create
    @investment = Investment.new

    @investment.save
    redirect_to @investment
end


private
  def investment_params
    params.require(:investment).permit(:title, :description))
  end
end
```

I've also added extra strings to the database. Adding them to the params didn't seem to work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have double parenthesis at the end of the line

```
 params.require(:investment).permit(:title, :description))
```